# Docker LAMP Stack

Tags: php, apache, docker, lamp, dockerfile

I'm just learning Docker and I've managed to get a few containers going, but I'm trying to learn how to run everything on separate containers. SO, the idea is that I have:

- Mysql Container (working)
- PHP-FPM Container (partially working)
- Apache Container (not working yet)

I've setup my LAMP stack on a vagrant and tested it out just using phpmyadmin. I then split off MySQL into a container and it all worked beautifully.

I then got php-fpm running but I can't figure out how to get Apache to use it. My config is obviously wrong which I understand, the problem is I don't know how to get it right.

THe plan is that once that's working I should be able to easily move Apache over and have them all playing nicely together.

I'm just using the official mysql:latest, so that's easy.

I'm using a Dockerfile from the official php.

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
# Install modules
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd 
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

run cmd

```
docker run -d --name php56 -v /var/log/php:/var/docker/php5-fpm -p 127.0.0.1:9000:9000 php56
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/010-phpmyadmin.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.docker
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5-fpm.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
   AddHandler php5.fcgi .php
   Action php5.fcgi /php5.fcgi
   Alias /php5.fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Clearly "FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.fcgi" is wrong as I'm running php-fpm on a container not on the local vagrant, but what should it be?

I have read a number of articles about the benefits of having separate apache/nginx and fpm or having fpm and Apache/nginx on the same container. I'm happy to hear more on that, but I'm really after a solution to this problem. I don't know that I'll ever use this in production, but I'm trying to learn Docker.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access files from the other container simply expose a volume on the php container and start your Apache container with --volumes-from and point it at the name of your php container so it can find the .cgi file needed.

Comment: Yep, I guess I can do. I'm trying to do it one step at a time to learn a little more about how it all works, so at the moment Apache isn't in a container, it's just inside the Ubuntu VM. So at the moment only php and mysql are in containers.

Answer (score 0):

you can check mine apache+php5-fpm+mysql+phpmyadmin

there:

https://bitbucket.org/haveapland/docker/src

don't expose ports outside, use links

and if you need to run php script from shell inside the container just type:

```
docker exec -it name_of_php_fpm_container bash
```

to stop all containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

to remove all containers:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: "[PHP development environment with Docker](http://bsosna.com/2017/03/12/php-development-environment-with-docker/)"
Good luck!